# What sort of microphone is used in smart speakers?

Tags: microphone

I am trying to make my own "smart speaker" using a Raspberry Pi.

I bought a mini USB microphone but it generates lots of static and the volume is extremely low unless you speak directly into the microphone:
https://core-electronics.com.au/mini-usb-microphone.html

So clearly I need some other sort of microphone - something that people can talk to from several feet away, ideally something very small, and it needs to be USB.

Can anyone guide me a to what type of microphone is suitable for this?

Comment: research MEMS mics

Answer (score 3):

Almost all smart speaker use  omnidirectional MEMS microphones. They are small, good and inexpensive. Something like this perhaps: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/knowles/SPW0690LM4H-1/423-1423-1-ND/8573349

You won't find these with a USB interface, they are either analog, PDM and in rare cases I2S.

Keep in mind that smart speakers have multiple microphones and do A LOT of local signal processing to "clean up" the voice quality: beam forming, noise suppression, de-reverberation, voice activity detection, etc. A single far-field microphone in a room is not going to give you great speech pickup, at least not without some serious post processing.

Comment: Don't forget huge compression to make it loud enough from across the room.